# Apollo dev tools not showing any data

Tags: apollo-client

The dev tools version is 4, same situation in Chrome as in Firefox.
"@apollo/client": "^3.5.7",

```
const createApolloClient = (authToken) => {
  return new ApolloClient({
    link: new HttpLink({
      uri: "https://api2s.geomar.net.pl/v1/graphql",
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${authToken}`,
      },
    }),
    cache: new InMemoryCache(),
    connectToDevTools: true, // should not be necessary but added just in case
    defaultOptions: {
      watchQuery: {
        fetchPolicy: "cache-and-network",
        pollInterval: 3000,
      },
    },
  });
};
```

The application is React + Vitejs, if it makes any difference...
No idea where to start any debuging, please help...

Comment: Same here, react + vitejs, using Brave. I'll only get the very first query on my page. Everything else not showing up in the dev tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not make it work so I ended up using **GraphQL Network Inspector** Chrome extension
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/graphql-network-inspector/ndlbedplllcgconngcnfmkadhokfaaln

No alternative for Firefox...

Answer (score 1):

Some other users reported a similar problem in the github project on this [issue](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client-devtools/issues/822). I'm curious if this may be what's occurring on your end.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue, adding [`connectToDevTools: true` to the `ApolloClient` constructor](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/development-testing/developer-tooling/#configuration) helped to solve it